# Industrial Networks

Tags: control, protocol

I have been trying o figure out the differences in the several fieldbus protocols used in control networks in industry, what are they?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could point us to these protocols. Otherwise this will likely be closed as "not a real question". What do you see the differences are? Or what area are you confused by.

Comment: [Which of these (over 300 protocols) are you talking about](http://mv-sirius.fh-offenburg.de/ecmIC/FieldbusSites.htm)?

Comment: What "fieldbus" protocols?  *It is difficult to tell what is being asked here*.

Comment: Not sure this helps much but I assume the OP means http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieldbus

Comment: I have been exposed to protocols like DeviceNet, CANopen, Profinet, Profibus, EtherCat, ASI; and because i don't have much of a networking background, i have a hard time understanding the functional differences, it would be helpful if you could just pick two of the protocols i mentioned and describe with their differences.

Comment: This makes no sense. How can us picking two protocols at random be a solution to your problem? It's not clear at all what your problem actually is. Only one more vote to close anyway, so your chance to fix this is dwindling rapidly. I'm actually surprised it lasted this long (14 hours) already.

Comment: @Olin - done...

Comment: @OlinLathrop, please do note to users that a close is just freezing answers until the question can be fixed, they then have a few months to fix it before someone will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SCADA controllers use Fieldbus with a wide variety of physical interfaces such as the ones you mentioned. You can choose any physical medium for your bus to meet **your noise immunity and cost needs** if you have no existing "plant" or "hub" of devices to connect. If you define your **needs** then you can choose suitable interface type as fiber has more noise immunity than twisted pair with cost trade-off for example.

There are many suppliers; and this is by no means my preferred supplier, but they have good documentation.  http://catalog.phoenixcontact.net/phoenix/treeViewClick.do;jsessionid=QGBCnkcfF9nrQsJLnbnSqSYdSpy8n26H4Bq7ml2dLvcQJbVP1DGk!1814543188?UID=608303396&parentUID=171918&reloadFrame=true

THis replaces the older technology of 4~20 current loops and uses less current.

"Fieldbus works on a network structure which typically allows daisy-chain, star, ring, branch, and tree network topologies."  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieldbus_Foundation

Advantages include; 
low cost, reliable RS485 TPC half duplex with power over data.